# How to save google authentication for android between sessions

Tags: android, google-app-engine

My app uses google authentication to login against an app engine backend. When i successfully log in my DefaultHttpClient gets a cookie from my App Engine domain, i was wondering if it were possible somehow to persist this cookie and then reapply it in the case of the app starting again at a later point to save from logging in every time the app starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. In Android, I used App Engine Client to authenticate with app engine app and use  `HTTPConnection` to set Cookie

```
HttpURLConnection connection;//Init connection here
connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", mCookie);
```

mCookie is stored in *SharedPreferences* after you login success.

Note: In my project, Using other method(eg. HttpClient) to set cookie for each request was difficult and when I use HttpURLConnection it works well.

Tips: You should use Appstats for debugging this to see if the cookie is actually sent to the server.

Good luck

Comment: So switch from using DefaultHttpClient to HttpURLConnection? And how did you actually save that cookie between sessions? Setting it sounds really nice and easy that way, just wondering how you've saved it inbetween because it sounds like you're doing exactly what i'm doing.

Comment: oh, i think i just got it. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can save it to database or use SharedPreferences. In my case, I used SharedPreferences

Comment: I followed many instruction to try to set cookie for HttpClient but still not success. But when I come to HttpURLConnection, it works like a charm. I suggest you should use AppEngineClient https://code.google.com/p/aerc/ to authenticate, It is using HttpURLConnection in its implementation

Comment: Ah, yeah. I've been having a look at AERC. I used to use it in my project, can't remember anymore why i dont. Might go back now. Thanks a bunch :)